# Instance of '_MapStream<FirebaseUser, User>' showing instead of uid in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want **uid** value overhere but when i use **_auth.user.toString()** it returns Instance of '_MapStream instead of uid , i am stuck over here , new to flutter

**somefile.dart**

```
Future<void> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verified = (AuthCredential authResult) {
        _auth.signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationId);
        print(phoneNo);
        //print uid value over here
        print(_auth.user.toString());
    };
```

**somefile2.dart**

```
 User _userFromFireBaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
        return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
      }



   Stream<User> get user{
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFireBaseUser);
       // .map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFireBaseUser(user));
  }  




 Future signInWithOTP(smsCode, verId) async {
   try{
        AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
        AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
        FirebaseUser user = result.user;
        return _userFromFireBaseUser(user);

   }
   catch(e){
        print(e.toString());
        return null;
   }
  }
```

**user.dart**

```
class User{

  final String uid;

  User({this.uid});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. It is because 'user' is an instance of Firebase user. To get uid, just use 'uid' property as :

```
_auth.user.uid
```

Comment: the getter id isn't defined for the class Stream<User> , this is what its saying

Comment: Goto somefile2.dart. Print the result after line FirebaseUser user = result.user; e.g. print(user.uid). Let us know what is the result. Alternatively, you can put a breakpoint at this line and see the content.

Comment: somefile2.dart is returning the userid correct , but somefile.dart is returning the getter id isn't defined for the class Stream<User>

Comment: In somefile.dart, what does print(_auth.user.userid) do ? Did you debug and check content of _auth.user ?

Comment: bro check the code above first , userid is nothing its uid and _auth.user.uid is not possible because its a syntax error not runtime or compile error

Comment: Sorry, I meant, _auth.user.uid

Comment: please help . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use stream directly with .uid

I am using StreamProvider to resolve the stream first

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
final uid = user.uid;
```